# Indexed Network drive as a document library content

Tags: document-library, crawling, index

I have indexed a drive that I would like to make its content directly visible in a document library.

Exemples:

Shared drive/sales content should appear in Sharepoint/sales/document library

Hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do that.

Best options are to use a page viewer web part, pointed to your network share to  make it appear as if the files are in SharePoint or create a search result that combines your external share and your document library content into a single result source and make it available via search results web parts.

Comment: Thx! 
How permissions will be handled?

Comment: In both cases, they should behave the same way, you'll only see what you have access to see.

Comment: I have an other question slightly related, I have the content trimmed and the scroll bar gets added!couldn't find where I give it the whole page length.

Comment: More specifically, make the "Main" container adapt to the browser page height.

Comment: You'll have to roll that yourself, with either CSS or Javascript to dynamically resize it

Comment: and where can I do that ?